# Compile all files in subfolder from SASS to CSS

Tags: css, sass, gulp, gulp-sass

I'm trying to compile a set of scss files into a single css file. For example, here is my folder structure:

```
theme
    - assets
       - src
         - sass
            - config
               - _grid-system.scss
               - _variables.scss
            - _client-styles.scss
            - _typography.scss
         - styles.scss
```

From the above, I'm looking to compile `_client-styles.scss` and `_typography.scss` into one css file. This new CSS file will sit in the same folder and will be called core.css (will sit under the `sass` folder).

I have `gulpfile.js` set up which compiles all `.scss` files into css in the same folder. But don't know how to approach this conversion as I want to ignore the `styles.scss` file.

Current `gulpfile.js`:

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
var postcss = require('gulp-postcss');

var paths = {
    styles: {
        src: 'modules/**/*.scss',
        dest: 'modules'
    }
}

function scss() {
    return gulp.src(paths.styles.src)
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(sass({ outputStyle: 'compressed' }))
        .pipe(postcss([autoprefixer()]))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.styles.dest));
}
exports.scss = scss
function watch() {

    scss();

    gulp.watch(paths.styles.src, scss);
}
exports.watch = watch
```

What `styles.scss` looks like (for reference):

```
@import "config/**.scss";  
@import "client-styles.scss";
@import "typography.scss";
```

How do I go about this? Compile the '_client-styles.scss' and '_typography.scss' file into 'core.css' that will sit under `sass` folder:

theme
    - assets
       - src
         - sass
            - config
               - _grid-system.scss
               - _variables.scss
            - _client-styles.scss
            - _typography.scss
         - styles.scss
         - core.css (new file here)

Comment: gulp.src(paths.styles.src,"!<path to your scss file>") -- try replacing with this

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `core.scss` file where you will import all sass files in the subfolders like this:

```
// change the path accordingly    
@import "./sass/**/*.scss";
```

Using [gulp-sass-glob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sass-glob) you can pipe it in your `gulpfile.js` this way:

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
var postcss = require('gulp-postcss');
var sassGlob = require("gulp-sass-glob");

var paths = {
    styles: {
        src: 'modules/**/*.scss',
        dest: 'modules'
    }
}

function scss() {
    return gulp.src(paths.styles.src)
        .pipe(sassGlob())
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(sass({ outputStyle: 'compressed' }))
        .pipe(postcss([autoprefixer()]))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.styles.dest));
}
exports.scss = scss
function watch() {

    scss();

    gulp.watch(paths.styles.src, scss);
}
exports.watch = watch
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to compile many SCSS files would be to use the [many-to-many](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/cli/dart-sass#many-to-many-mode) compilation mode on the dart sass cli tool.

In my project, SASS is being managed by NPM, so to achieve this you can do:

- If sass is not already installed with NPM, `npm install --save-dev sass` to install sass as a dev dependency for your current project or `npm install -g sass` to install it globally on your system
- `npx sass some_path/scss_dir:some_other_path/css_output_dir` to compile all the `*.scss` files in `some_path/scss_dir` and output them (with source maps) to `some_other_path/css_output_dir`

  - `npx sass some_path/scss_dir:some_other_path/css_output_dir --watch` will re-build the compiled CSS when any of the SCSS files are changed